# Force a linebreak Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-applications

I'm trying to create a line break in the html page after data is received from the server, using append method. This is a snippet of my code (jquery):

```
ws.onmessage = function(evt) $("#display").append("message: " + evt.data);
```

This is the div in the html:

```
<div id ="display"></div>
```

I'm a newbie, so please forgive the simplicity of the question.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to append a <br> tag?

Comment: yes but when i try <br> it doesn't create a new line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
ws.onmessage = function(evt) $("#display").append("message: " + evt.data + "<br />");
```

another option could be

```
ws.onmessage = function(evt) $("#display").append("<p>message: " + evt.data + "</p>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking a linebreak won't be displayed in your HTML, you would need to use a `<br/>` tag to create a break. In JavaScript a new line character would be `\n`, but you probably want to use:

```
ws.onmessage = function(evt) $("#display").append("message: " + evt.data + "<br/>");
```

If you are pre-formatting the `<div>` as if it were a `<pre>` tag and actually want a new line:

```
ws.onmessage = function(evt) $("#display").append("message: " + evt.data + "\n");
```

Your HTML for your div is a little off as well, you should remove the space between `id` and `="display"`

```
<div id="display"></div>
```